# How to maintain custom session for custom login and registration account module in magento 1.9.2 community edition

Tags: php, session, magento, magento-1.9

I am developing a module in which I am creating separate account which not using anything of customer. I am not able to create a separate session for my module. I tried to study customer module's session.php but I didn't get it. I am not understanding this code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $namespace = 'customer'; 
}
```

Please guide me on how I can achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding `customer` namespace, I assume you are discovering `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php`File.

This is basically the namespace of your model, it holds for usage it like `Mage::getModel('customer/session')`.

So if your module named `yourCompany_yourModel` , you registered your `yourCompany_yourModel` model prefix in `config.xml` and created constructor as above in `app/code/local/yourCompany/yourModel/Model/Session.php`

if you make

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $namespace = 'yourModule'; 
        $this->init($namespace);
    }
```

then you can use it in your code like:

`Mage::getSingleton('yourModule/session')->setYourVariable($yourVar);`